# DataFrame.queryの使い方について

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-query/
にある、

```
print(df.query('name.str.contains("li")', engine='python'))
```

を真似してコーディングしているのですが、
raise NotImplementedError(f"'{node_name}' nodes are not implemented")
NotImplementedError: 'AnnAssign' nodes are not implemented
というようなエラーが出ています。

これは、ソースコードが悪いと言っているのか、環境設定（モジュールのインストールが足りてない、バージョンの選び方、その他ツールの設定）の問題を言っているのか、どちらですか？
現状

```
print(df.query('name:subname.str.contains("00")', engine='python'))
```

というふうになっていて、:が含まれていたりするのですが、そういうのは問題ありますか？

【環境について】
　●PyCharm
　　2021.3.3 (Community Edition)
　　Build #PC-213.7172.26, built on March 16, 2022
　・Python 3.9.7
　・pandas 12.1
　・numexpr 2.8.1
　・numpy 1.22.3

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

その様な場合はカラム名をバッククォートで囲みます。

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
  'name:subname': ['a', 'b_00', 'c', 'd']
})
>>> df.query('`name:subname`.str.contains("00")', engine='python')
  name:subname
1         b_00
```

Comment: metropolisさん。ありがとうございました。ご教示いただいた方法で、解決しました。